# What is the function of the amplitude of a plucked string depending on where it is plucked?

Tags: waves, string, normal-modes

Here is the image of the situation: [image]

Where L is the lenght of the string, A, the amplitude and p is a fraction of the string's lenght (where it is plucked = pL). So, here it is, How do I find an expression for the amplitude of the excited modes ($C_n$) depending on the fraction of the string's lenght (p)? 
I know that I probably need to use the Fourier series with the coefficient $C_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_{x_0}^{x_0 + L}y(x)sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})dx$, but I don't really understand why and I don't know what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

For educational reasons I carried out the [full derivation](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=17#pid451284) of a 1D vibrating string some time ago.

After variable separation, integration of the ODEs and application of the BCs I obtained:

$$y(x,t)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\cos\Big(\frac{n\pi ct}{L}\Big)\sin\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)$$

If the initial condition is $y(x,0)=f(x)$, then because the cosines all become $1$:

$$y(x,0)=f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)$$

The amplitude spectrum $A_n$ can be found using the Fourier series:

$$A_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^{L}f(x)\sin\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)dx$$

For the $A_n$ with a triangular $f(x)$, scroll down the link.

I obtained:

$$A_n=\frac{4ay_0}{n^2\pi^2}\sin\Big(\frac{n\pi }{a}\Big)$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got the expression for $A_n$, could you explain more the steps before you can get to this?

Comment: Did you mean the first or the second expression for $A_n$ in my answer?

Comment: yes sorry, I don't understand how you got to the second expression for $A_n$

Comment: If you follow that part of the derivation here:http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=18#pid451620 it is layed out in full detail.

Comment: Ah yes I see, you wouldn't happen to have the steps between the final integral and the final expression for $A_n$? I just try to get to it myself but it is not very successful...

Comment: I don't have it lying around, no. It's tedious, which is why I omitted it.. The hardest part are the integrals of the kind:$\int x\sin(qx)\text{d}x=\frac{\sin(qx)}{q^2}-\frac{\cos(qx)}{q}+c_1$. Then piece it all together.

Comment: ALright thank you very much!

Comment: I don't want to sound annoying but do you think that you could do the final steps that lead to your final answer? because I'm still trying to do it and I always end up with something different than you... I know that it may not seem very important but I need to show in detail how I can get to the beautiful and simple final expression that you got for $A_n$. Or I can show you what I did if you want, then you could spot the possible mistakes?

Comment: Are you taking into account that the symbols I use are different from yours?

Comment: Why not take your solution to the Math section of the network, to have it checked over?

Comment: Yeah I'll do that thanks!